# Prevent users to access to website using port 8080 (apache) when using Varnish (on port 80)

Tags: apache-2.2, port, varnish, seo

My configuration is very simple :

To avoid duplicate content, I want to prevent user to go on my website by hitting directly apache (which is running on port 8080).

I have setup a Varnish server listening on port 80, so I want to use only this to avoid bot indexing the same website on different port which may cause duplicate content issue.

I'm using a dedicated server with Debian 6.

My virtual host looks like :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.seek-team.com

    DocumentRoot ...
    DirectoryIndex app.php

    <Directory "/var/www/seek-team.com/current/web">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**How to prevent user to directly access to the website using port 8080 ? 
(but I still need varnish to hit apache correctly).**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind apache daemon to loopback interface and make Varnish to connect to `localhost:80`. Thus, varnish would be accessible to the world while apache would be accessible only locally.

Varnish config:

```
backend www {
.host = “localhost″;
.port = “80″;
}
```

Apache config:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
...    
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
...
```

Comment: Do you have an example please ? It looks obscure to me as i'm not a sys admin

Comment: I've just edited the answer and included the example.

Comment: Thx i'm going to test it ASAP.

Comment: @Tristan Did this actually work?

Answer (score 1):

Quickest option would be to simply bind the Apache instance to Localhost, so it would only be accessible from that machine.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
```

Alternatively you could tweak the permissions of your Apache Virtual host directory block to:

```
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1  #IP.OF.MY.PC
```

This is slightly more flexible, as you can add your own IP, or net range to the permitted IP list, to allow a select few direct access for diagnostic purposes.

Both option above assume the Varnish instance is running on the same physical server.

Answer (score 1):

Simply block the 8080 port with iptables for the outside world like this:

```
 # iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP

 # iptables -I INPUT -s localhost -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the traffic is all shut down. Varnish can't access to the port 80 (he his on the same server ofc)

Comment: What's the value in the .host section you have given in Varnish. Is it the network interface IP or localhost. It should be localhost, and it will work

Comment: Also, the sequence in which you executed the iptables rules also matter, it should be same as I pasted above.

Comment: I know this is what i did, but after that, my website didn't respond. I also tryed to put iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT but it didn't work.