# What is a reverse proxy exploit?

Tags: reverse-proxy, node.js, exploit

On [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/551700/apache-url-rewriting-in-reverse-proxy) I found this particular part of code in an Apache configuration file:

```
# rewrite rule to prevent proxy exploit
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^$
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/
RewriteRule  .*              -    [R=400,L]
```

**What is a proxy exploit?**

**How does it work and how does exactly these lines prevent the attack?**

Answer (score 1):

A reverse proxy exploit is this ability to take advantage of a vulnerability in a service acting as an intermediary redirector for client request to one or more backend servers/services.

Apache HTTPd can act as such gateway using its multi-protocol proxy/gateway features eg. mod_proxy & related modules.

Code presented use Apache mod_rewrite directives (RewriteCond here) is supposely aimed at mitigating an Apache Vulnerability related to how rewrite module process values received within incoming request URI.

**1 ) First rewrite condition**

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^$
```

- REQUEST_URI variable is the path component of the requested URI (without query string)
- ! : "not" (eg. not matching)
- ^ : "beginning of REQUEST_URI
- $ : "end of of REQUEST_URI value"

**2 ) Second rewrite condition**

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/
```

- REQUEST_URI variable is the path component of the requested URI (without query string)
- ! : "not"
- ^ : "beginning of REQUEST_URI value"
- / : "/" (literally), eg."slash separator"

**3 ) Rewrite rule**

```
   RewriteRule  .*              -    [R=400,L]
```

- . : "any single character"
- * : "Zero or more of previous character"
- - : "No modification to incoming URL
- R=400 : Redirect with HTTP status code 400 ("Bad Request")
- L : "Last" rule, stop processing