# Apache 2.4 vhost configuration - How to "hide" parts of the url for CMS and browser

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite, proxypass

Apache 2.4.38 on Windows

We are just about to start using a new content management system, Enonic, hosted in the cloud. I am now trying to configure an internal alias for the test instance to point to the instance in the cloud. This is quite straight forward using proxypass/proxypassrevers

```
ProxyPass "/"  "https://xptest.enonic.cloud/wwwt/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "https://xptest.enonic.cloud/wwwt/"
```

Problem is that there are several sites on the instance https://xptest.enonic.cloud and therefore we cannot expose the site using the root / - therefore www is added. Problem is that the CMS adds www as a prefix for all relative url's created by the cms. Meaning https://wwwt.mycorp.com/wwwt/corporate, but wwwt should not be there, it should be https://wwwt.mycorp.com/corporate

I did try this [serverfault.com:Apache URL rewriting in reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/551700/apache-url-rewriting-in-reverse-proxy) but no luck either, urls still contains the /wwwt/

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Comment: Thanks to https://dltj.org/article/apache-httpd-and-tomcat/ I'm almost there, will post an answer with full configuration when all is solved. For now it works for all except the relative url / - in other words the home / root. That one still adds /wwwt/

Answer (score 0):

The solotion as described in the post https://dltj.org/article/apache-httpd-and-tomcat/ to use RewriteUrl [P] and not ProxyPass. RewriteUrl hides /wwwt/ from being showed in the browser, and all links are now shown as expected in the CMS.